# Не переходит по внутреннему руту react-router-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Вопрос: Использую react-router-redux@5.0.0-alpha.9
В App.js работает корректно, но при попытке перейти в другой внутренний рут меняется линк в адрессной строке, но не меняется сам компонент, хотя если вручную сменить линк - компонент отобразиться корректно.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём ошибка? Может я не совсем понимаю как нужно использовать внутренние руты..

Упрощенный вид архитектуры:

index.js

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root"),
)
```

App.js:

```
const App = ({ changeActivePage, activePage }) => (
  <div>
    <Header changeActivePage={changeActivePage} activePage={activePage} />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage} />
      <Route path="/news" component={NewsPage} />
      <Route path="/services" component={ServicesPage} />
      <Route path="/gallery" component={GalleryPage} />
      <Route path="/newspaper" component={NewspaperPage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
)
```

NewsPage.js:

```
render() {
    const { news, article, getNews, getArticle } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/news"
        render={props => (
          <NewsArray {...props} news={news} getNews={getNews} getArticle={getArticle} />
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path="/news/:id"
        render={props => <Article {...props} article={article} getArticle={getArticle} />}
      />
    </Switch>
        <Filter getNews={getNews} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, что-то поменялось с версией, но в **react-router-redux v5.0.0-alpha.6** вот так работало:

App:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <div className="App">
      <Route exact path="/" component={MainRoute} />
      <Route path="/first" component={First} />
      {/* и т.д. */}
    </div>
  </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

Some route:

```
class First extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container"></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, но это не вложенный рут